# Why the empty object { } and the empty array [ ] aren’t falsy, how they are truthy, by definition

Tags: javascript, arrays, null, is-empty, falsy

ref:https://medium.com/coding-at-dawn/what-are-falsy-values-in-javascript-ca0faa34feb4 by Dr. Derek Austin

Since I have started my development career with JavaScript this question always arise in mind how??

Truthy values include the **empty object** {} and the **empty array** [] — since they aren’t *falsy*, they are *truthy*, by *definition*.

```
let empty = []
empty ? console.log("truthy") : console.log("falsy") // truthy
empty = {}
empty ? console.log("truthy") : console.log("falsy") // truthy
```

where,

```
"" ? console.log("truthy") : console.log("falsy") // falsy
```

Comment: They are truthy because the language defines them as such. Is there a compelling reason for that *not* to be the case?

Comment: You *may* discuss about empty arrays, but what does it mean for an *object* to be "empty"? Even "empty objects" have all sorts of properties, so when is an object really "empty"? This becomes pretty tricky pretty quickly, so they're simply truthy.